# Can we [sort] out this [alphabetical] soup?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

We have both [alphabetical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphabetical) (414 questions) and [alphabetical-sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphabetical-sort) (78 questions).

The questions in each tag look similar, and I can't think of a difference in meaning. They should be merged.

Although alphabetical-sort lacks a wiki and has fewer questions, I think it should be the preferred tag, as "alphabetical" looks like it wants to modify another tag (such as [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sorting)) rather than stand on its own.

Comment: Depending on the question, it may be related to collation.